# SSD I/O errors & fails self tests

Tags: ssd

Background:

The Windows 10 PRO couldn't boot normally, BSOD occurred & self system recovery couldn't fix the problem. It was possible to boot Windows in safe mode, however.
The ADATA SU750 SSD was dismounted and plugged into another PC.

1. I tried to clone SSD with a help of Linux `dd` program, but some I/O errors occurred.
2. Latter, I ran health test using ADATA SSD ToolBox. SSD passed a Quick Diagnostic Scan, but Full Diagnostic Scan couldn't be launched. I ended up with a warning prompt meaning, according to ADATA Support, that there are some bad blocks in the SSD.
3. I used a `ddrescue` to clone and retrieve data (succeeded).
4. Then I intended to erase everything on SSD using Secure Erase (Erase Disk) by Parted Magic Linux distribution, but the program calculated ridiculously long time (equivalent of 47 days) to accomplish this task, so I gave up.
5. Instead, I deleted all partitions with GParted and used ADATA SSD ToolBox to erase SSD (succeeded).
6. From that moment, ADATA SSD ToolBox could accomplish Full Diagnostic Scan without any error warnings. Also, Parted Magic could perform both SSD self-tests (short & extended) successfully, with no errors at all.

My question is: Is it clever to use this SSD still? Or maybe it should be replaced with a new one?

```
-- S.M.A.R.T. ------------------------------------------------------
ID Cur Wor Thr RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 100 100 _50 000000000000 Read Error Rate
05 100 100 _10 000000000058 Reallocated Sectors Count
09 100 100 __0 000000000872 Power-On Hours
0C 100 100 __0 000000000FCE Power Cycle Count
A0 100 100 _50 000000000058 Uncorrectable sectors count when read/write
A1 100 100 _50 000000000063 Number of Valid Spare Blocks
A3 100 100 __0 000000000063 Number of Initial Invalid Blocks
A4 100 100 __0 0000000058C6 Total Erase Count
A5 100 100 __0 000000000016 Maximum Erase Count
A6 100 100 __0 000000000002 Minimum Erase Count
A7 100 100 __0 00000000000B Average Erase Count
94 100 100 __0 000000010A52 SLC Total Erase Count
95 100 100 __0 000000000044 SLC Maximum Erase Count
96 100 100 __0 000000000006 SLC Minimum Erase Count
97 100 100 __0 000000000022 SLC Average Erase Count
9F 100 100 __0 000000000000 DRAM 1 bit Error Count
A8 100 100 __0 000000000044 Max Erase Count of Spec
A9 100 100 __0 000000000064 Remain Life
B1 100 100 __0 000000000000 Total Wear Level Count
B5 100 100 __0 000000000000 Total Program Fail Count
B6 100 100 __0 000000000000 Total Erase Fail Count
C0 100 100 __0 000000000027 Power-Off Retract Count
C2 100 100 __0 000000000034 Temperature
C3 100 100 __0 000000000000 Hardware ECC Recovered
C4 100 100 __0 000000000001 Reallocation Event Count
C7 100 100 __0 000000000001 Ultra DMA CRC Error Count
E8 100 100 __0 000000000063 Available Reserved Space
F1 100 100 __0 000000023726 Total LBA Written
F2 100 100 __0 0000000306EB Total LBA Read
F5 100 100 __0 000000033ABF Flash Write Sector Count
```

Comment: Please add to your post the SMART attributes of the disk.

Comment: Your SSD is throwing errors and you’re unable to access the drive.  Why would you risk using the drive in its current state? The drive in my opinion likely is at or near it’s lifetime write capability. I am guessing the drive is from 2019 so that would be nearly 5 years which is around the lifespan of the type of drive you have

Comment: @harrymc I added SMART to my post.

Comment: @Ramhound This SSD is rather new. According to ADATA Warranty Checker, it's under warranty until 2025-01-31 (product is protected by a 3 year limited warranty from the purchase date)

Comment: @Andrew Morton This SSD belongs to a friend of mine. I was asked to help in getting PC back to life, which I did. The data were recovered & backed up to the img file on external HDD. SDD, after erasing, doesn't show any errors, so all data were restored again. PC works fine now. 
I will have to advise my friend, what to do next, whether she should leave an old SSD or buy a new one (she is not a wealthy person). At this stage, the vendor most likely won't accept warranty claims as there is no evidence of any problem (she will have to buy a new SSD therefore). That's why I'm asking for a help.

Comment: With `Reallocated Sectors Count` being `0x58`, `Is it clever to use this SSD still?` No, absolutely not. `as there is no evidence of any problem` I am not seeing how that's the case, although I admit that it is probably tough to get the vendor to offer a replacement anyway.

Answer (score -1):

According to the SMART data, this SSD is in a very good state.

There are 88 Uncorrectable sectors which were probably successfully
recovered since Reallocated Sectors Count is also 88.
But as a disk would normally have thousands of spare sectors, 88 are not
an indication of an imminent failure.

You may use this SSD safely. But as there were some past problems,
I advise keeping an eye on the SMART data and watch for further
degradation. If no such degradation occurs for the coming months,
then the disk can be declared as healthy.